# Does Gsuite support the creation of custom fields that can be used to discover information when used as search strings?

Tags: csv, google-admin-sdk

I want to bulk-load some emails in the Gsuite account using a csv file. However there's this field called "building id" which is NOT REQUIRED but is handy for my requirements; I just realized that out of the box, Gsuite cannot locate a record by the mentioned field as the search term. My question is, is there a workaround to this problem? Better yet, does Gsuite support the creation of custom fields that can be used to discover information when used as search strings? Anyone who knows a solution to this problem?

Comment: Which "building id" specifically are you talking about?

Comment: Just like first name, last name, email address etc., there's also a field(optional) called "building id" which I wanted to leverage for my needs. However, when I upload data, I cannot search for records based on that field in the admin search bar.

Comment: Is the `buildingId` the one from the [Reports API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/resources.buildings/list)? Also, how exactly are you importing and retrieving the information?

Comment: I populate information in an excel sheet, then save it as a csv file. Finally, I import the csv file using the bulk upload option in the Gsuite admin panel.

Answer (score 0):

When using the `Directory API` to list the members, using the **query** parameter to get the members with a specific `buildingId` is **not** an option. The available queries that can be made are listed [here](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/search-users#fields).

However, you can create your own `custom field` using the below [Directory API schemas.insert](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/schemas/insert) request:

```
POST https://admin.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/customer/{customerId}/schemas
```

With the following request body:

```
{
  "schemaId": string,
  "schemaName": string,
  "fields": [
    {
      "displayName": "",
      "fieldName": "",
      "fieldType": ""
    }
  ],
  "displayName": string,
}
```

Afterwards, when you want to retrieve the users with a particular value, you will have to make the below request:

```
GET https://admin.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users
```

With the following fields:

- `customFieldMask` > set to the name of the schema;
- `projection` > set to `custom`;
- `query=schemaName.FIELD='VALUE'` > this will query the users who have the field from the custom field with the value `'VALUE'`.

#### Reference

- [Directory API Users:list](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users/list);
- [Directory API Schemas.insert](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/schemas/insert).

Comment: This is great, but how can I leverage this information in Google Admin?